# Superscript hours, minutes, seconds over decimal for angles

Tags: math-mode, superscripts, overset

In this example (from the U.S. Naval Observatory's *Almanac for Computers*), there is a nice, compact notation for angles where the units of the angle (either degrees or hours, minutes seconds) is shown above a decimal.

[image]

How can I reproduce this? An overset `m` is close, but the decimal is centered directly below the `m`, which gives the wrong impression.

```
35\overset{\mathrm{m}}{.}421
```

[image]

Is there a way I can move the decimal closer to the "5" (in this example)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Define your own `\dotdeg` and `\dotem`, possibly in the following way:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\dotdeg}{\rlap{.}^\circ}
\newcommand{\dotem}{\rlap{.}^m}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item
  $\theta = 8 \dotdeg 855 + 0 \dotdeg 98561 t + 1 \dotdeg 916 \sin (0 \dotdeg 9856 t - 3 \dotdeg 819)
    + 0 \dotdeg 020 \sin( 1 \dotdeg 9712 t - 7 \dotdeg 638 )$

  \item
  $T = 35 \dotem 421 + 3 \dotem 94244 t - 4 \dotem 0 \arctan [ ( \tan \theta ) / 0.91747 ]$
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

---

A bit cleaner interface that takes a decimal number as argument for `\dotdeg` and `\dotem` (requires a period `.` within the decimal):

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\addtodot#1.#2\relax{#1\rlap{.}^{\dotadd}#2}
\newcommand{\dotdeg}[1]{\def\dotadd{\circ}\addtodot#1\relax}
\newcommand{\dotem}[1]{\def\dotadd{m}\addtodot#1\relax}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item
  $\theta = \dotdeg{8.855} + \dotdeg{0.98561}t + \dotdeg{1.916} \sin ( \dotdeg{0.9856} t - \dotdeg{3.819} )
    + \dotdeg{0.020} \sin( \dotdeg{1.9712} t - \dotdeg{7.638} )$

  \item
  $T = \dotem{35.421} + \dotem{3.94244} t - \dotem{4.0} \arctan [ ( \tan \theta ) / 0.91747 ]$
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

A `stackengine` approach.  I create `\angdot` that takes an optional argument (default `\circ`) to set above the dot.  The alignment is to the left.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand\angdot[1][\circ]{%
  \stackengine{0pt}{.}{${}^{\mathrm{#1}}$}{O}{l}{F}{F}{L}}
\begin{document}
$\theta = 8\angdot855 + 3\angdot[m]94244 t$
\end{document}
```

[image]